# Mini JavaScript thread pool with maximum number of concurrently running tasks

Tags: javascript, promise

I wrote this mini thread pool in JavaScript that takes a maximum number of concurrently running tasks and runs them in the order it was given. I appreciate any feedback or review. Thank you.

```
class TaskPool {
  constructor(poolSize) {
    this.poolSize = poolSize;
    this.queue = [];
    this.runningTasks = 0;
    this.scheduled = null;
    this.id = 0;
  }

  backgroundRunner() {
    if (this.queue.length) {
      if (this.runningTasks < this.poolSize) {
        const index = 0;
        const [[task, id]] = this.queue.splice(index, 1);
        this.runningTasks++;
        task(id).finally(() => {
          this.runningTasks--;
          this.backgroundRunner();
        });
      } else {
        console.log('queue is full');
        if (!this.scheduled) {
          console.log('scheduled for later');
          this.scheduled = setTimeout(() => {
            this.backgroundRunner();
            this.scheduled = false;
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  run(task) {
    this.queue.push([task, ++this.id]);
    this.backgroundRunner();
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
function task(id) {
  //create an ID
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    console.log('running task #', id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done running task #', id);
      resolve();
    }, 400);
  });
}

const pool = new TaskPool(3);
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  pool.run(task);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ud3vxh8s/)

Comment: Maybe this steps from some confusion with promises? javascript is single threaded. promises are just a fancy alternative to using callback, and all callbacks execute on the same thread - one callback after another. Look up "Javascript event loop" to learn more about how this works. If you really want to do threading, you can use "web workers" to do the job. But a "promise pool" is just overhead that'll slow things down, not speed them up.

Comment: @ScottyJamison This was an interview question. I wanted to get feedback for my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- It's not entirely clear until getting to the bottom of the class what the `queue` array holds. Maybe call it something more precise like `unstartedTasks` or `unstartedTasksQueue`.
- You can return early to avoid nested indentation - cutting down on unnecessary indentation can make it clearer exactly which block a `}` at the end corresponds to. For example, `backgroundRunner` could be made to be:

  ```
  backgroundRunner() {
    if (!this.queue.length) {
      return;
    }
    // lots of code
  ```
- The `scheduled for later` section looks superfluous since unstarted tasks will be run immediately upon the completion of a task, due to the

  ```
  task(id).finally(() => {
    this.runningTasks--;
    this.backgroundRunner();
  });
  ```
- When you want to remove the first element from an array and use it, use `shift`, not `splice`. This:

  ```
  const [[task, id]] = this.queue.splice(index, 1);
  ```

  can be

  ```
  const [task, id] = this.queue.shift();
  ```
- Unless the insertion index of the task *needs* to be saved, you could simplify the queue by incrementing and using the `id` not when the task is pushed, but when the task gets executed. This way the queue only needs to be an array of functions, not an array of `[task, id]`s.

See below for the version I'd prefer, if a class-based implementation is required. I use `#` to clearly distinguish what's exclusively private methods and properties from a public method:

```js
class TaskPool {
  #unstartedTasksQueue = [];
  #runningTaskCount = 0;
  #id = 0;
  #runningTaskLimit;
  constructor(runningTaskLimit) {
    this.#runningTaskLimit = runningTaskLimit;
  }
  insertTask(fn) {
    if (this.#runningTaskCount === this.#runningTaskLimit) {
      this.#unstartedTasksQueue.push(task);
    } else {
      this.#startTask(fn);
    }
  }
  #startTask(fn) {
    this.#runningTaskCount++;
    fn(this.#id++).finally(() => {
      if (this.#unstartedTasksQueue.length) {
        this.#startTask(this.#unstartedTasksQueue.shift());
      } else {
        this.#runningTaskCount--;
      }
    });
  }
}

function task(id) {
  //create an ID
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('running task #', id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done running task #', id);
      resolve();
    }, 4000);
  });
}

const pool = new TaskPool(3);
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  pool.insertTask(task);
}
```

But all the private methods and properties, despite making the code's *intent* a bit clearer, can look a bit ugly. Since the external user of the class is only interfacing with 2 things (the constructor, and the `run` method), I'd prefer to make a *function* instead of a class, which returns the `run` (or, as I've named it, `insertTask`) method, so as to rely on the closure instead of on `#`s:

```js
const makeTaskPool = (runningTaskLimit) => {
  const unstartedTasksQueue = [];
  let runningTaskCount = 0;
  let id = 0;
  const startTask = (fn) => {
    runningTaskCount++;
    fn(id++).finally(() => {
      if (unstartedTasksQueue.length) {
        startTask(unstartedTasksQueue.shift());
      } else {
        runningTaskCount--;
      }
    });
  };
  return (fn) => {
    if (runningTaskCount === runningTaskLimit) {
      unstartedTasksQueue.push(task);
    } else {
      startTask(fn);
    }
  };
};

function task(id) {
  //create an ID
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('running task #', id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done running task #', id);
      resolve();
    }, 4000);
  });
}

const insertTask = makeTaskPool(3);
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  insertTask(task);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Poor jargon leads to bugs

An important part of coding is correctly describing and/or interpreting from natural language what the code does or should do.

As natural language can be very ambiguous, descriptions use a lot of jargon that have very specific meaning within the context of programming, often completely different from the colloquial meaning.

If you are unsure about the correct use of programming jargon you should look it up.

#### Concurrent

<sub>From google</sub>

> *"Concurrent tasks are multiple tasks that progress at the same time but they are not executed simultaneously"*

#### Thread

<sub>From google</sub>

> *"A thread is a unit of execution. Multithreading is a technique which allows a CPU to execute many tasks of one process at the same time. "*

- *"Multithreading"* and *"Thread"* are interchangeable in JavaScript (and most languages) as JavaScript does not provide a mechanism to distinguish the two.
- In JavaScript a *"Thread"*  has a specific property of being *"Non blocking"*
- In JavaScript a *"Thread"* is AKA a *"worker"*.

### Bug #1

The question's title and question

> *"Mini JavaScript thread pool with maximum number of concurrently running tasks"*

> *"I wrote this mini thread pool in JavaScript that takes a maximum number of concurrently running tasks..."*

Threads run in parallel or concurrently via web workers. If I create a task I would expect your code to do as advertised.

```
function task(id) {
     return new Promise(completed => {
          while (Math.random() > 0.00001) {}
          completed();
     });
}

const pool = new TaskPool(3);
pool.run(task);  // Blocks for indeterminate time
pool.run(task);  // this line is not executed until previous task is complete
```

However as your code is not threaded and the tasks do not run concurrently, the first task blocking all execution until it resolves its promise.

### Bug #2

Your code assumes that the task returns a promise. As you do not vet the argument `task` in `run(task) {` to make sure it is a function, and when you attempt to execute it, if it does not throw *"task Is not a function"* it will throw *".finally is not a function"* if `task` does not return a `promise`.

Because the task count `this.runningTasks++;` is incremented before the error each time there is this error the pool size is permanently reduced by one.

### Redundant code.

The polling of `TaskPool.backgroundRunner`

```
 else {
    console.log('queue is full');
    if (!this.scheduled) {
      console.log('scheduled for later');
      this.scheduled = setTimeout(() => {
        this.backgroundRunner();
        this.scheduled = false;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

And property

```
  this.scheduled = false;
```

can be completely removed from the code without changing its behavior at all.

There is no need to poll `backgroundRunner` as the `task.finally` has a 1 to 1 match with completed tasks.